# System contains no element on Aggregate call

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have this code that throws "Sequence contains no elements" exception:

```
autoRefreshWorker = new AutoRefreshWorker(AutoRefreshData, () => {
                var items = ((DocumentListDataSource)TableView.Source).Items;
                
                return items.Any() 
                    ? items.Aggregate((i1, i2) => i1.Id > i2.Id ? i1 : i2) 
                    : items.FirstOrDefault();
            },
                AutoRefreshIntervalMs);
```

I was not able to reproduce the error myself. But on AppCenter I can see that lots of users experience this error very often and the stack trace shows the following:

```
Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] func)
DocumentsListViewController.<ViewDidAppear>b__38_0 ()
DocumentsListViewController+AutoRefreshWorker.<Start>b__6_1 ()
AsyncHelpers+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<InvokeOnMainThreadAsync>b__0 ()
AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state)
NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply ()
(wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
Application.Main (System.String[] args)
```

I know that calling Aggregate() on empty set throws that exception. But in my code I check if items contains any element before calling Aggregate. So it is not clear to me what can cause this exception in my code. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the full exception stacktrace to your question ? It can be helpful to answer your question. Did you try to debug ? doing so would reveal which method is throwing the error.

Comment: I don't know what the cause is, but if you're using .NET 6+ (the tags don't indicate) or, I believe, MoreLinq you can replace the `Aggregate()` call with `items.MaxBy(i => i.Id)`.  Also, when `items.Any()` returns `false` returning `default(itemType)` would better communicate the intent than `FirstOrDefault()` since there definitely isn't a first element in that situation.

Comment: @EnricoMassone the problem is that i was not able to reproduce the error myself, I can see the Stacktrace on AppCenter and it shows Enumerable.Aggregate that throws the error

Comment: Is it possible, for any weird race condition, that the content of items is changed by another thread after the evaluation of items.Any() and before the evaluation of items.Aggregate() ?

Comment: If you want to exclude this possibility you can try to clone the collection (via items.ToList() for instance) and to work with the clone instead of the items variable.

Comment: Is it possible that some items are `null`? In this case `i1.Id` throws exception

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i guess in that case it would be "Null reference exception", but i get "Sequence contains no element" exception

Comment: @EnricoMassone yes, seems like it was race condition indeed, thanks for hint